# Chinese school group stereotypes?

Tags: vocabulary

In the west there are a lot of different groups in school. For instance this list of [High school stereotypes](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=High%20school%20stereotypes) mentions preps, jocks, geeks, etc.

Of course, even translating these groups directly wouldn't mean much to the average Chinese person who has little to zero knowledge of western school life.

For Chinese school groups, I don't know much other than 学霸 and 学渣. Maybe, it is just that limited? I would assume 00后 vocab would be more plentiful though.

Comment: schoolyard bully 校園欺凌者 school（yard）bullying 校園欺凌 well known in China

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha, that is an interesting question, I am going to try to list all the stereotypes I know.

First I will list some common ones regarding academic performance

> 学霸，very good student with hard working
>
> 学神，excellent student with little effort put in, also doing very well in nearly all other aspects you can think of, like sport clubs, video games and so on
>
> 学痞，academically excellent, little effort put in, difference with 学神 is, 学神 is more “仙” while 学痞 is more of an ordinary guy
>
> 学渣，not doing academically well because of no hard working
>
> 学酥，looking good when no exam is going on, will be found out to be 学渣 once exam comes, that is why they are called 酥，once being touched, they become “渣”
>
> 学屌，talented but not hard working students, performance varies with the effort they put in, but they do not care
>
> 学婊，always pretend to fail the tests but always end up with better grades than most of others, not a welcomed type

Then some regarding appearance

> 高富帅 or 高帅富，as the name suggests, tall, rich and handsome guy
>
> 白富美，again, as the name suggests, girl who is rich, beautiful and with fair skin
>
> （男）屌丝，it is not a good word and is ONLY used for self reference, it means someone who is poor and ugly
>
> 女屌（丝），the female version of （男）屌丝，the rule is the same, ONLY self reference

And some others

> 宅男，guys who love comics and or video games, seldom appear publicly
>
> 宅女，female version of 宅男
>
> 逗逼/逗比，a funny guy, but use with care as it might sometimes be derogatory

I will keep this answer updated if I could think of any others.